# Hosting my Angular SPA with ServiceStack self-hosted service

Tags: angular, nosql, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack to build a small RESTApi self-hosted service with a NoSQL database and everything is perfect (not using .Net Core).  Now I would like to build some maintenance screens using Angular and I wonder if I can or should embed inside my service or should I deploy my SPA separately?  The thing is that I don't want IIS or big or complex infrastructure to host it.  The customer would only have to install the service and have access to the API and also to a web site to do maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should typically go with the simplest solution first which would be to embed it inside your Service (unless you have a good reason not to) as enables a single deployment unit with less moving parts.

For reference you can look at [ServiceStack's Angular SPA Template for .NET Framework](https://github.com/NetFrameworkTemplates/angular-spa-netfx) to see an example of integrating ServiceStack with an Angular App.

Comment: thanks.  I was wondering if you have a simple guide that would help on what to do to serve angular from inside a self-hosted windows service.  Kind of like the one you had before with Razor.  I am just starting so I miss a lot of pieces...

Comment: There’s no guide, I’d just copy the files + npm config from the template. An SPA is mostly static files so it doesn’t matter where you host it, the main difficulty is getting the npm config/build system right (which the templates are pre-configured with). Although I personally wouldn’t use Angular, Vue is much simpler and it’s possible to build without npm which is what was used to build [Redis Vue](https://github.com/NetCoreWebApps/redis).